# MAMP cannot connect to SQL server within a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am quite new to the PHP world. I have installed MAMP on my Mac. This is the code I have written to connect to MySQL:

```
<?php
// Connect to the database server
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", “root”);
if (!$dbcnx) {
  echo( "<P>Unable to connect to the " .
      "database server at this time.</P>" );
  exit();
}
?>
```

MySQL has already started and is running. I am not sure why am I not able to connect.

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to find the error in your echo.

Comment: Remove the @ symbol from mysql_connect. It will suppress any errors that have occurred.

Comment: Thanks for reply... I am getting error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: What does a traceroute localhost provide? Sometimes the Mac is not able to resolve "localhost" properly ;-) In addition, you should use the native MySQL installation.. there is everything prepared and maybe also running so you have two mysql instances at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    // Connect to the database server
    $dbcnx = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$dbcnx) {
      echo( "Cannot connect to database  due to ". mysql_error());
      exit();
    }
?>
```

Since you are getting Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) there is no need of giving password to connect with the database.So try with password ''.

> Note:- mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0,and will be removed in the future.Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used

Answer (score 0):

Your code has smart quotes around the password. Try replacing them with regular quotes. If you have not changed the default MAMP password, this should work:

```
<?php
// Connect to the database server
$dbcnx = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if (!$dbcnx) {
  echo( "<P>Unable to connect to the " .
      "database server at this time.</P>" );
  exit();
}
?>
```